# android dependency of different activities

Tags: java, android

I have different activities that they wait for a event to occur.the are dependent to each other.for example my class called A that create instance of B class, calls a function of B class and B class wait for C class wait for user to push a button after that B class should call a function in A class:
this is structure:
this is my c class that wait for a button to press.
I don't want to use static methods.is there a better way instead of using interface?

```
public class c extends activity {

    public c(){
          new A;
    }
}
```

this is my A class that call B class:

```
public class A {

    public A(){
          new B;
    }
    public call B()
    {
         //call a B function
    }

}
```

and this is my B class:

```
public class B  {

    public call A()
    {
         //call a A function
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you wanna use Interface?

Comment: @Kunu because i don't know it is the proper way to do or not.we can use broadcast for example

Comment: I think it will be easiest and best way.

Comment: @kunu is there something like event handler to get an action and do something and returns the results?

Comment: Why don't you try Event Bus?